# How to check if a booking exists within the time frame?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, pdo

Im working on a meeting room booking system and i am having trouble figuring out if a room is taken within a set timeframe, i am using the current format for dates and have the type set to `DATETIME` in the table: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS`

This is my current code:

```
//Function to check if a booking exists:
function bookingExist($DateStart, $DateEnd, $RoomNo) {
    global $DB;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE date_start = :dateStart AND date_end = :dateEnd AND room_no = :roomNo";
    $Q = $DB->prepare($sql);
    $Q->bindParam(':dateStart', $DateStart);
    $Q->bindParam(':dateEnd', $DateEnd);
    $Q->bindParam(':roomNo', $RoomNo);
    $Q->execute();

    if ($Q->rowCount()) {
        //A record exists...
        return true;
    } else {
        //no record exists
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this in the sql query ?

example: Room A is booked between 2016-03-31 15:00:00 and 2016-03-31 17:30:00 User then tries to create a new booking for room A for 2016-03-31 16:30:00 - 2016-03-31 17:00:00 and thsi should return 1 record as there is a booking

Comment: The room is taken from date and time A to date and time B. So if either the start or end of your new time frame is between A and B it is taken. Is that what you need in SQL?

Comment: @Renan here is an example:
Room A is booked between 2016-03-31 15:00:00 and 2016-03-31 17:30:00

User then tries to create a new booking for room A for 2016-03-31 16:30:00 - 2016-03-31 17:00:00 and thsi should return 1 record as there is a booking

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM bookings
WHERE
  (
    :dateStart BETWEEN date_start AND date_end
    OR :dateEnd BETWEEN date_start AND date_end
    OR date_start BETWEEN :dateStart AND :dateEnd
  )
  AND room_no = :roomNo
```

This will give you zero rows, if the room is not booked in you given timespan :dateStart - :dateEnd.
`:dateStart BETWEEN date_start AND date_end` will check if it's already booked at starttime, `:dateEnd BETWEEN date_start AND date_end` will check if its booked at the end time and the last one `date_start BETWEEN :dateStart AND :dateEnd` is also important, it checks if the room is book in between (shorter period for example)

EDIT: OR times and no AND ;)

EDIT2: To exclude the start and end times, you have to expand the `BETWEEN` keyword and make the relation only be a `<`:

```
SELECT *
FROM bookings
WHERE
  (
    (date_start < :dateStart AND :dateStart < date_end)
    OR (date_start < :dateEnd AND :dateEnd < date_end)
    OR (:dateStart < date_start AND date_start < :dateEnd)
  )
  AND room_no = :roomNo
```

Comment: the :dateStart should it be my column name or the actual date ?

Comment: `:dateStart`  is your variable `$DateStart` and `date_start` is your column. I have only used the same name sheme as you in your question

Comment: What if a booking ends at 17:00 today, and i want to book a meeting from 17:00 to  18:00 ?

Comment: Actually it would returning the booked room. You could exchange `BETWEEN` by `min <= expr AND expr <= max` (e.g. `date_start <=  :dateStart AND :dateStart <= date_end`) and then strengthen the `<=` to a `<`  (`date_start < :dateStart AND :dateStart < date_end`)

Comment: any idea on how to avoid it? ie remove 1 minute from the end dates and show them as end date + 1 min ?

Comment: see above comment.

Answer (score 0):

what about using BETWEEN in the sql query? you need to set the date/time parameters you are checking against (which will be the second user's requested dates / times in the given example).

```
$firstDate = //start of time period you are checking;
$lastDate = //end of time period you are checking;
 $Q->bindParam(':firstDate ', $firstDate );
 $Q->bindParam(':lastDate ', $lastDate );

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE :date_start BETWEEN :firstDate AND :lastDate  AND room_no = :roomNo";
```

Comment: Like this: ```"SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE date_start BETWEEN :dateStart AND date_end BETWEEN :dateEnd AND room_no = :roomNo"```

Comment: I get an error when running the query:
```#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '14:00:00 AND 2016-03-31 17:00:00 AND room_no = 1 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1```

The query:
```SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE date_start BETWEEN 2016-03-31 14:00:00 AND 2016-03-31 17:00:00  AND room_no = 1```

Comment: looks like you are missing the colon in fornt of date_start - should be the parameter ":date_start"

Comment: its date, figured i didnt quote the date

Answer (score 0):

## Check before INSERT

### INSERT INTO .... SELECT .. WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)

CASE

> [booking1 10/7/21 11:00 - 11:30]
>  [---new--- 10/7/21 11:30 -
> 11:20]
>  [booking2 10/7/21 12:00 - 12:30]

You can insert booking if the booking does not EXSIST using the fallowing syntax:

```
-- new booking [b1][new][b2]
SET @s = '2021-07-10 11:30:00';
SET @e = '2021-07-10 12:00:00';

INSERT INTO Appointments
        (col1, col2, starts, ends) 
    SELECT 'some data', 'some data', @s, @e
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT id FROM Appointments -- search for collision points
        WHERE 
            ((starts <= @s AND @s < ends)
            OR (starts < @e AND @e <= ends)
            OR (@s <= starts AND starts < @e)
            ))
        AND (1=1) -- some other conditions
;
```

If no data will be returned in `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT...)` statement `INSERT` will be proceed. If `SELECT` returns at least one row `INSERT` will not get executed.

The above example allows for booking start and end to overlap with new booking. Notice like new booking starts at 11:30. At the same time at 11:30 ends booking which is already in our imaginary database. Same applies to time in which new booking ends - it also overlap with start of booking nr 2 and this is ok. The above query works with this kind of situation. If you would use BETWEEN instead this would not cover this cases.

In most cases this will produce unexpected results:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT id FROM your_table
    WHERE 
        ((@s BETWEEN starts AND ends
            OR @e BETWEEN starts AND ends
            OR starts BETWEEN @s AND @e))
        AND (1=1)) -- replace (1=1) with other mandatory conditions
    LIMIT 1;
```

This will produce the correct results:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT id FROM your_table
    WHERE 
        ((starts <= @s AND @s < ends)
            OR (starts < @e AND @e <= ends)
            OR (@s <= starts AND starts < @e))
        AND (1=1)) -- replace (1=1) with other mandatory conditions
    LIMIT 1; conditions
```